# fail to copy file from one vm (windows ) to another vm (windows ) with ansible

Tags: ansible

it is possible to copy file from one vm (windows ) to another vm  (windows ) with ansible

```
- script: test.ps1
```

Z: is network map
copy z:\PROGRA~1\test\File.txt C:\Users\file.txt

```
failed with error:
changed: [{{ host1 }}] => {"changed": true, "rc": 0, "stderr": "copy : Cannot fi
    nd drive. A drive with the name z does not exist.\r\nAt C:\\Users\\vagrant\\AppD
    ata\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1427807499.79-10385112351761\r\n7\\test.ps1:1 char
    :1\r\n+ copy z:\\PROGRA~1\\DyadicSec\\ssl\\192.168.50.13.cert C:\\Users\\192.168
    .50.12.cert\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (z:String) [Copy
    -Item], DriveNot \r\n   FoundException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNot
    Found,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Copy \r\n   ItemCommand\r\n \r\n", "stdout":
     ""}
```

if I run the ps1 on the vm its work fine

Answer (score 0):

Driver isn't mounted I guess.

```
$ echo -e 'copy : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'z' does not exist.\r\nAt C:\\Users\\vagrant\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1427807499.79-10385112351761\r\n7\\test.ps1:1 char:1\r\n+ copy z:\\PROGRA~1\\DyadicSec\\ssl\\192.168.50.13.cert C:\\Users\\192.168.50.12.cert\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (z:String) [Copy-Item], DriveNot \r\n   FoundException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Copy \r\n   ItemCommand\r\n \r\n'
copy : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name z does not exist.
At C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\ansible-tmp-1427807499.79-10385112351761
7\test.ps1:1 char:1
+ copy z:\PROGRA~1\DyadicSec\ssl\192.168.50.13.cert C:\Users\192.168.50.12.cert
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (z:String) [Copy-Item], DriveNot 
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Copy 
   ItemCommand


$
```